# How would I return a Firebase custom token if the generation of the custom token is asynchronous?

Tags: java, heroku, firebase, firebase-authentication, spark-framework

I'm using the Spark Framework hosted on Heroku and I  have this in my `main`: method in my server

```
post("/token", (request, response) -> "Hello World");
```

That's working fine, however, I want to actually send a custom token, and not just "Hello World".

So, logically, I would need this:

```
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
String uid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
post("/token", (request, response) -> auth.createCustomToken(uid));
```

However, `createCustomToken` returns a `Task<String>` and not a `String`. So, I have to do:

```
auth.createCustomToken(uid).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String s) {

            }
        });
```

However, in this form:

```
post("/token", (request, response) -> auth.createCustomToken(uid).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String token) {

            }
        }));
```

All I really still returned was a `Task<String>`. I need to return `token` from the `onSuccess()` method, but I can't since it's an inner class.

What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

I was running into a similar problem at Google App Engine. I had to verify a firebase token at server side but the response were sent back async from firebase. (
[Verify Firebase Token at Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41446582/verify-firebase-token-at-google-app-engine))

You can try the following code instead of using a OnSuccesListener

```
Task<String> authTask = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createCustomToken(uid);

try {
    Tasks.await(authTask);
} catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e ) {
    log.severe(e.getMessage());
}

String myToken = authTask.getResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createCustomTokenAsync(UID).get()
```

It returns a custom token in a string. Got it from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fi2dv6NcHWA