# Rolling a user authentication system for Android app

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, authentication

I'm a bit confused on how I can implement a user system into my application.

For a small overview, the mobile application needs to allow users to login or register, follow other users, and favorite/like items.

I've checkout out the documentation on Google Cloud Platform for implementing User Auth:

- https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect
- https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/users/
- https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/oauth/

I've used Parse in the past, and would expect the Firebase User Auth system to offer a similar experience, however due to Firebase conflicts with App Engine, that route is a no-go.

I understand there is also the User API, which can be used for things like restricting Cloud Endpoints calls to logged in users.

How can I roll a user auth system for my application? The best solution that comes to mind would be to just store user emails and passwords in Google Cloud Datastore, and check if the combination exists when a user logs in. However, I'm fairly unfamiliar with creating user systems and this seems like it would come with some sort of security issues.

Comment: Which Firebase conflicts with Google App Engine?

Comment: Apparently using Firebase with App Engine Standard Environment requires manual scaling: `To use Firebase with App Engine standard environment, you must use manual scaling.` from https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/firebase-app-engine-android-studio

Answer (score 1):

you can use Firebase Authentication with Google App Engine. Your information that you have to use manual scaling instance is not correct. This was a bug and were fixed. Please see the following post for more informations

[Verify Firebase Token at Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41446582/verify-firebase-token-at-google-app-engine)

Comment: Ah, yes. Manual scaling is required if one uses a long running Firebase listener in an AppEngine application. Regardless, i'd still like to know how I can role my own user system without Firebase.